# Print specific instances of json response

Tags: python, json, api

So I am using the urban dictionary api, and the code works perfectly as I would like: I'm going to use `chicken` as my term.

```
import json 
import requests 

url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"
querystring = {"term":"chicken"}
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "KEY"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
json_data = response.text 
json_object = json.loads(json_data)
print(json.dumps(json_object, indent = 4))
```

If I run this, I get the following which is the correct output, but I want to only print out the definition.

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "definition": "A [kilogram] of [cocain].  Dealers started calling kilos \"[birds]\" which then evolved into \"chicken.\"",      
            "permalink": "http://chicken.urbanup.com/1180537",
            "thumbs_up": 2947,
            "sound_urls": [
                "http://api.twilio.com/2008-08-01/Accounts/ACd09691b82112e4b26fce156d7c01d0ed/Recordings/RE18c37ff43a6fc6dce8d9d533e7e4042b"
            ],
            "author": "DEKE",
            "word": "chicken",
            "defid": 1180537,
            "current_vote": "",
            "written_on": "2005-04-11T11:41:04.000Z",
            "example": "Person 1) [How much] you [got left]?\r\n\r\nPerson 2) A [quarter] chicken.",
            "thumbs_down": 941
        },
        {
            "definition": "To lack courage and [bravery]. [Unskilled], stupid, afraid, loser, [coward]",
            "permalink": "http://chicken.urbanup.com/7399878",
            "thumbs_up": 180,
            "sound_urls": [
                "http://api.twilio.com/2008-08-01/Accounts/ACd09691b82112e4b26fce156d7c01d0ed/Recordings/RE18c37ff43a6fc6dce8d9d533e7e4042b"
            ],
            "author": "Freak Out Guy",
            "word": "chicken",
            "defid": 7399878,
            "current_vote": "",
            "written_on": "2013-12-10T16:49:06.660Z",
            "example": "He was so afraid she [thought] he was [a chicken].",
            "thumbs_down": 49
        }
    ]
}
```

I've seen that you can do `print(json_object['list'][0]['definition'])`, but it only prints out the first definition. How can I print out all the instances of definition like:

```
Definition 1: A [kilogram] of [cocain].  Dealers started calling kilos \"[birds]\" which then evolved into \"chicken.\"
Definition 2: To lack courage and [bravery]. [Unskilled], stupid, afraid, loser, [coward]
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use the dump, u can use the json_object instead. Like this:

```
import json 
import requests 

url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"
querystring = {"term":"chicken"}
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "KEY"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
json_data = response.text
json_object = json.loads(json_data)
#json_object = json.dumps(json_object, indent = 4)
print(json_object["list"][0]["definition"]) # you can use the for statement to get all the definitions
```

(Edit) All the definitions example:

```
import json 
import requests 

url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"
querystring = {"term":"chicken"}
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "KEY"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
json_data = response.text
json_object = json.loads(json_data)
#json_object = json.dumps(json_object, indent = 4)
for i in json_object["list"]:
  print(i["definition"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  for idx, entry in enumerate(json_object['list'], 1):
    print(f'Definition {idx}: {entry["definition"]}')
```

output

```
Definition 1: A [kilogram] of [cocain].  Dealers started calling kilos "[birds]" which then evolved into "chicken."
Definition 2: To lack courage and [bravery]. [Unskilled], stupid, afraid, loser, [coward]
```